# How to get the text fields values in the controller class without using any scripts

Tags: visualforce, controller

Im having a VF page it has some text fields and one button . On clicking the button , the values in the text field should be passed to the controller class to save in the database . Can this be achieved . If yes , direct me .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think this is one way

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="False" controller="textInputsCon">

<apex:form >

   Input Text1 <apex:inputText value="{!inputText1}"/>
   Input Text2 <apex:inputText value="{!inputText2}"/>

    <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveList}"/>
</apex:form>
```

controller

```
    public with sharing class textInputsCon {

     public String inputText1{get;set;} // input text1 value  from vf
     public String inputText2{get;set;} // input text2 value  from vf

      public void saveList(){

        salesObj  salesObjInst = new salesObj(); //  Either salesObj is standard or custom object

        salesObj.field1 =  inputText1;  // Field Assignment
        salesObj.field2 =  inputText2;  // Field Assignment

        insert  salesObj; // DML Operations

      }  

}
```

Another way , if you want call save action from the command button with out navigating to controller , you can use java script remoting.

Define one java script function same as a object, and call this function from the onclick event of button, check the below link

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm

Answer (score 1):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_methods.htm

You can reference the above document link to understand the concept of getter and setter in the sfdc.

Getter fetches the data from controller on to the visualforce page

Setters passes data from the visualforce page to apex controller class

Action methods are the methods invoked on the click of command button or link.

The order of execution is

1)All getters run first
2)Before your action methods all the setters get executed .

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/index.htm

Refer the workbook to get started with some basic examples and below wiki guide

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce