# How to store/post/bind input field (lookup) value of VF page in SF database?

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

I am developing a VF page where all lookup fields (for both parent & child object) will be replaced by autocomplete/typeahead. It is suggesting perfectly for lookup fields, but can't store the selected value into the database, therefore, the field value for that lookup is empty after creating the record.
[image: autocomplete]
From the image, typeahead/autosuggestion is working good, but when I select a value, click SAVE button of the page, this lookup field is not filled with the selected value. I have used SELECT2 3.4.2 version to build the autocomplete component, & the reason why field value is not posting is i have used inputText in component controller.

```
<apex:inputText style="{!Style}" styleClass="auto{!randomJsIden}" value="{!cacheField}" /> <apex:outputPanel id="hiddenPanel"> <apex:inputText value="{!targetField}" id="hiddenField" styleClass="hiddenField{!randomJsIden}" style="display:none"/> </apex:outputPanel> <script>v2{!randomJsIden} = new typeahead{!randomJsIden}({});</script>
```

I find that a good way to store inputText into database is mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14675/how-to-get-the-text-fields-values-in-the-controller-class-without-using-any-scri) . But, it only works for Sobject (I have sobject where it is not working, I have also List where this technique is throwing error).
The component code in the VF page is

```
<c:TypeAheadComponent allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="General_Ledge_Account__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!targetField}" style="width:15rem" />
```

In summary, I am trying to perform autocomplete for lookup fields in VF page (parent record & multiple children record are creating from this VF page). Autocomplete is fine (collecting data from database), but whatever I am selecting from VF page is not Stored in the database. Any idea how can I use inputText to store/bind user selected data into the backend database?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to give your primary record to the component.

---

```
// In page's controller
public SObject record { get; set; }
public ControllerConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
    record = ctrl.getRecord();
}
```

---

```
// In component controller
public SObject parentRecord { get; set; }
public String fieldName { get; set; }
```

---

```
<!-- in component -->
<apex:attribute name="record" assignTo="{!parentRecord}" type="SObject" description="" />
<apex:attribute name="targetField assignTo="{!fieldName}" type="String" description="" />
<!-- some time later ... -->
<apex:inputHidden value="{!parentRecord[fieldName]}" id="..." />
```

---

```
<!-- back in the page ... -->
<c:TypeAheadComponent record="{!record}" ... />
```

Comment: But, I have mutiple records to be created from this single VF page.

Comment: @tanmoy You can bind whichever record you feel like. For example, if it's in a loop: `<apex:iteration value="{!recordList}" var="aRecord"><c:TypeAheadComponent record="{!aRecord}" ...` The point is, you simply need to bind directly to the record in question.

Answer (score 0):

According the logic you have written, it looks like that you are trying to store value  of input text to the Sobject's lookup field. For example if you have `TestG2`, you are trying to assign it to Lookup type field which ultimately will throw exception when insert/update happen.

Reason is lookup fields always have `Id` of the records instead of name. So, you typehead component showing those value must have Id behind as they are record of some object. Store and set that Id to `inputText` instead of the name visible on page.